# conditional statements to run mysqli queries

Tags: php, mysqli, conditional-statements

This script I am working on retrieves emails from a database and if they meet any of the conditions, an email will be sent and the database will be updated stating that an email was sent.

I can the get the script to do that, but I can't get it to iterate over all of the emails inside the array. It will run the script for one email and then it will have an error: call to a member function execute() on a non-object. So what I understand from this is that when the foreach loop iterates over another email, there is nothing inside that variable for the query to insert into the database.

If I run the script again by refreshing the page, it will insert the email that it didn't during the previous call but it will give the same error for the next email inside the array.

**So my question is: how can I get my script to iterate through all of the emails within the array without it giving an error?**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$today = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a');

$time = time();

require('addrow_info.php');
//connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $database);
if(!$mysqli){
die('Not connected :' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
}

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM abandoned WHERE orderStatus IS NULL ORDER BY time DESC");
if(!$query){
die('Invalid query :' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
}

while($email = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

$abandoned[] = array(
    'email' => $email['email'],
    'time' => $email['time'],
    'status' => $email['orderStatus'],
    'attempts' => $email['attempts']
    );
}

$mysqli->close();

//open new connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost',$username,$password,$database);
if(!$mysqli){
 die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
}

foreach($abandoned as $viewAbandoned){

$timeAbandoned = strtotime($viewAbandoned['time']);

if($timeAbandoned < strtotime('-1 hour') && $viewAbandoned['attempts'] == '0'){

    echo "Order by " . $viewAbandoned['email'] . " was abandoned more than 1 hour ago<br/>";

    //send email to remind them of items in their cart
    $to = 'josan.iracheta@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'new abandoned email';
    $message = $viewAbandoned['email'];

    $sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message);

        if(!$sendmail){
            echo "Mail not sent!";
            }
            else{
            echo "Mail sent!";

            //update database with email attempt

             $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE abandoned SET attempts = '1' WHERE email = '".$viewAbandoned['email']."' ");
             $updateResult = $update->execute();

            }//end if Mail was sent, database was updated with attempt

    }//end if abandoned cart is more than 1 hour old

    //if email has been sent once, send after 6 hours
    elseif($timeAbandoned < strtotime('-6 hours') && $viewAbandoned['attempts'] == '1'){

    //send email to remind them of items in their cart
    $to = 'josan.iracheta@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'new abandoned email';
    $message = 'Second notice ' . $viewAbandoned['email'];

    $sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message);

        if(!$sendmail){
            echo "Mail not sent!";
            }
            //if mail is sent
            else{
            echo "Mail sent!";

            //update database with email attempt

             $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE abandoned SET attempts = '2' WHERE email = '".$viewAbandoned['email']."' ");
             $updateResult = $update->execute();

            }//end if Mail was sent
            //database was updated with attempt

    }

    //send email after 24 hours
    elseif($timeAbandoned < strtotime('-24 hours') && $viewAbandoned['attempts'] == '2'){

    //send email to remind them of items in their cart
    $to = 'josan.iracheta@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'new abandoned email';
    $message = 'third notice' . $viewAbandoned['email'];

    $sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message);

        if(!$sendmail){
            echo "Mail not sent!";
            }
            else{
            echo "Mail sent!";

            //update database with email attempt

             $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE abandoned SET attempts = '3' WHERE email = '".$viewAbandoned['email']."' ");
             $updateResult = $update->execute();

            }//end if Mail was sent
            //database was updated with attempt

    }

    //send email after one week
    elseif($timeAbandoned < strtotime('-168 hours') && $viewAbandoned['attempts'] == '3'){

    //send email to remind them of items in their cart
    $to = 'josan.iracheta@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'new abandoned email';
    $message = 'It has been one week already' . $viewAbandoned['email'];

    $sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message);

        if(!$sendmail){
            echo "Mail not sent!";
            }
            else{
            echo "Mail sent!";

            //update database with email attempt

             $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE abandoned SET attempts = '4' WHERE email = '".$viewAbandoned['email']."' ");
             $updateResult = $update->execute();

            }//end if Mail was sent
            //database was updated with attempt

    }

}//end foreach loop
```

Comment: Why are you closing your DB connection, then opening it up again? Anything you try to retrieve from your first query, will be lost for the next.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I closed it because I saved the fetched data into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your program is breaking when it hits your `$updateResult = $update->execute();` line because `$mysqli->query()` return true for **DML** queries that are successful. [Documentation Here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

I believe that if you remove the lines with the execute calls it should fix your issue.

If you want to keep the execute lines, you need to change `query()` to `prepare()`

Comment: should I execute the queries after the if/elseif statements?

Comment: `$mysqli->query()` already is executing your query. `execute()` is only needed when you use `prepare()` in place of `query()`

Comment: Yeah I understand the logic now. I looked at the code and at some of my other scripts and I realized how redundant that was. Thanks!